# Can I get DDL for a database clone in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have different clients and each client has its own database. Now for different clients our roles are named something like write_role_clientID. Now for any new client I want to clone an older DB but the roles should be for that clientID. I know I can get a DDL to create a DB but that doesn't include any privileges/grants. If somehow I can get the DDL for a clone because in a clone the privileges are also inherited by the objects then I might be able to manipulate the sql using code.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT GET_DDL('database', 'your_cloned_database')` should work fine over a cloned database. However, I'd be cautious using clones for new clients as they'll have access to data from the old client unless you go through every table and `TRUNCATE` all the tables (and be cautious around Time Travel!).

It's probably easier to do something like `SELECT REPLACE(GET_DDL('database', 'original_database'), 'old_client_id', 'new_client_id')` (you could probably even just `EXECUTE` that, but YMMV).

Comment: I want DDL of clone because when a clone is created the privileges are also inherited by all the objects inside that database. Normal database DDL do not have any grant queries.

Comment: I don’t believe you can use get_ddl to do this. However, you might be able to extract what you want from the QUERY_HISTORY view